# JavaScript obfuscation - Inline constants & rename public properties/methods

Tags: javascript, obfuscation

Are any of the popular JavaScript obfuscators capable of inlining constants and renaming public properties/methods of objects?

ie.

```
var CONST1 = 5;
var CONST2 = 10;

function Test() {
    abc = 123;
    this.xyz = 234;
}

Test.prototype = {
    do_it: function(argX, argY) {
        return (argX + abc) / CONST1 + (argY + this.xyz) / CONST2;
    }
};

document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
    x = document.getElementById("x").value;
    y = document.getElementById("y").value;
    alert("Done it: " + new Test().do_it(x, y));
}
```

- I would like CONST1 and CONST2 to effectively disappear and have their values inlined.
- I would like all of the names (abc, xyz, Test, do_it, argX, argY) to be replaced/mangled.
- I would like the obfuscator to assume that nothing external relies on any object/method/constant names in my source.

Can Google Closure or any other obfuscator do this?

Comment: Typo / new to javascript. :P Added example as I realized that it would probably just be compiled down to nothing if it wasn't tied to the user interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Closure Compiler can do so in advanced compilation mode, however annotations are required to prevent automatic removal of the `prototype` property.  For example, this:

```
var CONST1 = 5;
var CONST2 = 10;

function Test() {
    abc = 123;
    this.xyz = 234;
}

Test.prototype = {
    do_it: function(argX, argY) {
        return (argX + abc) / CONST1 + (argY + this.xyz) / CONST2;
    }
};
```

is annotated as this:

```
var CONST1 = 5;
var CONST2 = 10;

/** @constructor */
function Test() {

abc = 123;
this.xyz = 234;
}

/** @expose */
Test.prototype = {
do_it: function(argX, argY) {
return (argX + abc) / CONST1 + (argY + this.xyz) / CONST2;
}
};

window["Test"] = Test;
```

then when it is run, converted to this:

```
function a() {
  abc = 123;
  this.a = 234;
}
a.prototype = {b:function(b, c) {
  return(b + abc) / 5 + (c + this.a) / 10;
}};
window.Test = a;
```

Comment: Thank you for the info about annotations.

Comment: @graw: note that `do_it` has been renamed too, if you want to keep it as-is you'd need to do something like `Test.prototype["do_it"] = Test.prototype.do_it;`.

Comment: I wanted it renamed (well, not in my edited example but in the original one...). Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

Google Closure can do all of the above.  They have a web-based UI available at http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home for you to test with your own code.

Comment: Thank you, I've verified that it does this (in Advanced mode only) (and more... it inlines the entire method call). Can any of the others do it?